# Issues with Color-Coded Calculated Columns

Tags: 2010, calculated-column

I have a list with a series of columns that all return percentages. I have done the stop light chart with status columns but not percentages.  I have gone to 'Path to SharePoint' - the site everyone references and uses - but I can't get the code to work.

This is what I am using:

```
="<DIV style='position:relative;'><DIV style='background-color:"&CHOOSE(INT([Floor Area Eliminated]*10)+1,"red","red","OrangeRed","OrangeRed","DarkOrange","Orange","Gold","yellow","GreenYellow","LawnGreen","Lime")&"; width:"&([Floor Area Eliminated]*100)&"%;'> </DIV><DIV style='position:absolute; top:0px;'>"&TEXT([Floor Area Eliminated],"0%")&"</DIV></DIV>"
```

I have the javascript that goes along with it on the page and below the webpart.

My problem: It works on 2 fields. That's it. I have about 10 fields and the rest show the number and % but not the color. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. It seems like it should be so simple but it just won't work.

Thank you for any help offered.

Answer (score 0):

The *Path to SharePoint approach - the site everyone references* is based on the 2007 way of adding HTML to a List View.
It is kinda like trying to operate your iPhone 6 with an Apple-II manual and a great example of why you should exclude Google Results from over a year old in your searches.

Since SharePoint 2010 there is no need to add extra JavaScript to the page which translates text to HTML.

All you need to do is set the datatype of a Calculated Column to Number and your Formula will be interpreted as HTML.

Full explanation and *Pros* and *Cons* at http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How

I have an app in the store which does this Percentage-Bar (and does updating as well) so I was curious what your HTML code produced.
There were some issues with it, major one being you did not set a height on the colored DIV.

Formula that works:

```
="<DIV style=""position:relative;"">"
&"<DIV style=""height:1.5em;background-color:"
&CHOOSE(INT([Floor Area Eliminated]*10)+1,
  "red","red","OrangeRed","OrangeRed","DarkOrange",
  "Orange","Gold","yellow","GreenYellow","LawnGreen","Lime")
&"; width:"
&([Floor Area Eliminated]*100)
&"%;"">"
&"<DIV style=""position:absolute; top:0px;"">"
&TEXT([Floor Area Eliminated],"0%")
&"</DIV></DIV>"
```

Note: I am using the **double**-double-quote notation to get a regular double-quote in the HTML code. You can use a single-quote like you did. I find this notation easier to read, and it allows for the use of a single-quote in (optional) Javascript code added.

Note: For those on SharePoint 2013 (or Online); You can also do this with [CSR/Jslink code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-f1068b4b)
But putting it in a Calculated Column is a lot less coding, works anywere the  Column is displayed.